# Matlab - Numerical computation of integral in only one instruction line

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have done a little Matlab code which computes, for each input parameter, the value of an integral depending of this input parameter.

Finally, I get an array of output values and I plot the figure "output vs input".

Here's the code snippet (where `Omega*` are constant) :

```
j=1;
for z=z_begin:inter:z_final
dc1(j)=c/(H0*sqrt(abs(Omega1_k)))*sinh(sqrt(abs(Omega1_k))*quad(@(x)myfunc(x,Omega1_m,Omega1_red,Omega1_k),z_begin,z));
j=j+1;
end
```

So finally, I plot `dc1 versus z` data arrays.

Now I would like to know if the computation with loop can be done in only one instruction line.

Is there a way to avoid this loop and do this task on only one instruction line to get the `dc1` output array ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You coud use [arrayfun](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html), if you dont like the for loop, but arrayfun its still a loop under the hood.

Comment: thanks, it does the trick